# Does the Larmor precession of electron orbitals have any applications just as the precession of nuclei is used in NMR?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, magnetic-moment

Considering that electrons have a gyromagnetic value much higher than the proton and other nuclei, so inducing the precession is much easier to achieve then with the latter systems, I was wondering if the electron spin precession measurements were used in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, measurements of electronic spin precession can be done in the same way as nuclear spin precession.  The technique is known as [electron paramagnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance) (EPR) or electron spin resonance.  However, EPR is a lot less useful in practice than NMR, for a couple of reasons.  One reason is that the electron spins are part of the electron configuration that determines the local magnetic field in an atom or molecule, while the nuclear spins are largely independent spectators; this means that you can make changes to the nuclear spin configuration without really affecting the ambient fields.  There are are also issues having to do with the face that the electron spin states typically have much larger energy splittings, meaning that inducing electron spin transitions requires more energy transfer.